# Reading and appending to the same file

Tags: c, file

I am new to C programming and just writing a simple program to read all the lines from a text file and replace each number with a new one. Here is my code. It prints to the console for each line but not to the file. Can someone please suggest what is wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE * file_ptr;
    int num; 
    char line[128];
    file_ptr = fopen (argv[1], "a+");
    if(file_ptr==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file");
    }

    if(file_ptr!=NULL)
    {
        while(fgets(line,128,file_ptr)!=NULL)   
        {
            fputs("df",file_ptr);   
            printf("2");
        }
    }

    fclose(file_ptr);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `fclose` is reached weather or not `file_ptr == NULL`.

Comment: Why are you openning the file `a+`?

Comment: I have tried both r+ and a+ and I am just trying different options. I can change that as per my requirements to overwrite or append but the problem is I am not able to read and write to the same file using same pointer.

Comment: I'm disappointed with the downvotes on this question. There's compilable code, and there's an explanation of the undesired behavior (even if it's terse, it's sufficient to understand the problem). This is exactly what a debugging question should be like! Good luck with your learning.

Comment: due to the 'a+' mode on the fopen call, any writes would be to the END of the file, not to the current position.  Such an operation would move the 'file pointer' to the end of the file.  If you want to overwrite a spot in the file, you will need to use fseek() to adjust the 'file pointer' to the desired location in the file.  before doing a fgets(), the code should use ftell() to get/save the current position in the file.

Comment: If the compile step were to (properly) have all the warnings enabled, then several warnings would be issued. The first would be about the unused parameter 'argc' the next warning would be about the unused variable 'num'  BTW: the code should always check argc to assure a parameter is available, before accessing the parameter via 'argv'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you're reading and writing from the same file, and your reads and writes interact.

Opening the file with the mode `a+` (append, allowing reading) sets the file position at the beginning of the file, so the first call to `fgets` reads the first line. But in append mode, all writes are performed at the end of the file. So the first call to `fputs` sets the file position to the end of the file, then writes `df`. Since there's a single file position for both reading and writing, the next call to `fgets` is performed at the end of the file, and reads nothing.

The behavior of file position makes the mode `a+` appropriate mostly when you want to read the whole current content of a file and then add something at the end.

Note that the only way to modify the content in the middle of a file is to replace a sequence of bytes by a sequence of bytes with the same length. So you can replace `12` by `df`, but you can't replace `123` by `df`: if you set the file position where `123` is located and write `df`, you'll end up with `df3`. To replace numbers by strings of potentially different length, you'll need to rewrite the file as a whole

When you want to completely modify a file, there are three main techniques:

- Load the current content in memory, truncate the file to 0, write the new content.
- Open the current file for reading, create a new file, write the new content to the new file, close the old file, then move (rename) the new file to overwrite the old file.
- Rename the old file, create a new file with the original name, read the current content from the renamed file, write the new content and close the files.

The first method has a major downside: if your program crashes or the computer loses power, the file will be lost. Thus you should almost always use one of the other two approaches: they use more disk space but the added safety is almost always worth it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I will try the code following all three methods for practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
The following code, which incorporated several oversights in the OP code
will tell the user about any error conditions that occur

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE * file_ptr;

    char line[128];

    if( 2 > argc )
    { // then invalid number of parameters
        printf( "\nUsage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE );
    } // end if

    // implied else, file name parameter exists

    if( NULL == (file_ptr = fopen (argv[1], "a+") ) ) // open for read and append
    { // then fopen failed
        perror( "fopen failed" ); // output reason for failure to open file
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE );
    } // end if

    // implied else, fopen successful

    // note: second pass through this loop will fail as file pointer will be at end of file
    // always put literal first, so compiler will catch syntax errors
    while(NULL != fgets(line,sizeof(line),file_ptr) )
    {
        if( EOF == fputs("df",file_ptr) )// appends 'df' to end of file
        { // then fputs failed
            perror( "fputs failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, fputs successful

        printf("2");
        fflush( stdout );
    } // end while

    fclose(file_ptr);
    return(0);
} // end function: main
```